# Permission denied when running hive query

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

When I am trying to run simple SELECT in Hive I got following error:

```
Application application_1386250421542_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1386250421542_0001_000002 exited with exitCode: 126 due to: Exception from container-launch:
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: /bin/bash: /var/lib/hadoop/hadoop-yarn/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1386250421542_0001/container_1386250421542_0001_02_000001/launch_container.sh: Permission denied
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:464)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:283)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:79)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
```

I tried to change permissions, but without success. My hadoop is installed on RHEL.

**UPDATE**

This error happened on every MapReduce program, so Hive is not a problem here.

Comment: Have you given execute permission to the script?

Comment: @SSaikia_JtheRocker how can I? This file is created by hadoop itself, execute by hadoop and remove by hadoop. I cannot manage it rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in /etc/fstab. The partition for hadoop was mounted with `noexec`

Comment: can you pls explain in detail @garath . am facing the same prob.

Comment: In my case when i check fstab I saw that there was wrong permissions on hadoop partition