# Hadoop 2 IOException only when trying to open supposed cache files

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I recent updated to hadoop 2.2 (using this tutorial [here](http://codesfusion.blogspot.com/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html?m=1)).

My main job class looks like so, and throws an IOException:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.*;

public class UFOLocation2
{
    public static class MapClass extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable>
    {
        private final static LongWritable one = new LongWritable(1);
        private static Pattern locationPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]{2}[^a-zA-Z]*$");

    private Map<String, String> stateNames;

    @Override
    public void setup(Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            URI[] cacheFiles = context.getCacheFiles();
            setupStateMap(cacheFiles[0].toString());
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println("Error reading state file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
                    throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String line = value.toString();
        String[] fields = line.split("\t");
        String location = fields[2].trim();

        if (location.length() >= 2)
        {
            Matcher matcher = locationPattern.matcher(location);
            if (matcher.find())
            {
                int start = matcher.start();
                String state = location.substring(start, start + 2);
                context.write(new Text(lookupState(state.toUpperCase())), one);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupStateMap(String filename) throws IOException
    {
        Map<String, String> states = new HashMap<String, String>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            String[] split = line.split("\t");
            states.put(split[0], split[1]);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        stateNames = states;
    }

    private String lookupState(String state)
    {
        String fullName = stateNames.get(state);
        return fullName == null ? "Other" : fullName;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(config, "UFO Location 2");
    job.setJarByClass(UFOLocation2.class);

    job.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/kevin/data/states.txt"));

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

    Configuration mapconf1 = new Configuration(false);
    ChainMapper.addMapper(job, UFORecordValidationMapper.class, LongWritable.class, 
                Text.class, LongWritable.class,Text.class, mapconf1);

    Configuration mapconf2 = new Configuration(false);
    ChainMapper.addMapper(job, MapClass.class, LongWritable.class, 
                Text.class, Text.class, LongWritable.class, mapconf2);

    job.setMapperClass(ChainMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(LongSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(LongSumReducer.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);               
}
}
```

I get an IOException because it can't find the file "/user/kevin/data/states.txt" when it tries to instantiate the `BufferredReader` in the method `setupStateMap()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is deprecated and  [`Job.addCacheFile()`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#addCacheFile%28java.net.URI%29) should be used to add the files and in your tasks( map or reduce) files can be accessed with [`Context.getCacheFiles()`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobContext.html#getCacheFiles%28%29).

Comment: I beleive I tried do that and I got aorg.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException followed by a stack trace. I'll post it when I run the job later this evening

Comment: @webermaster Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428471/permission-denied-when-running-hive-query will help you.

Comment: That is not the issue

Comment: These things work but now I'm running into an IOException when it tries to open the file within the mapper

Answer (score 0):

//its fine addCacheFile and getCacheFiles are from 2.x u can use something like this

```
    Path path = new Path(uri[0].getPath().toString());
    if (fileSystem.exists(path)) {
        FSDataInputStream dataInputStream = fileSystem.open(path);

        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while (dataInputStream.read(data) > 0) {
            //do your stuff here
        }

        dataInputStream.close();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Deprecated functionality shall work anyway.